# How to replace a specific char in a string?

Tags: swift

I have tried to replace a specific char in a string. I want to replace the the seconde `o` for an `e`.  I have tried to use:

```
  var s   = "bolo"
  var charIndex = advance(1, 1)
  s.replaceRange(Range(start: charIndex, end: charIndex), with: "e")
  println(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the string startIndex (s.startIndex) when using advance as follow:

```
var s = "bolo"
let charIndex = advance(s.startIndex, 3)
s.replaceRange(charIndex...charIndex, with: "e")
println(s)  // "bole"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use too the function [stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:), in the following way:

```
var s = "bolooooooo"
s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("o", withString: "e", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: Range<String.Index>(start: advance(s.startIndex, 2), end: s.endIndex))
```

The output is :

```
boleeeeeee
```